# Calling an RESTFul using Spring-Android

Tags: java, android, spring, gson

Here is my Strifified json,

```
 {
       "Request":{
              "Object1":{
                 "Key1":"Value1"
              },
              "Object2":{
                  "Key2":"Value2"
              }
       },
       "Object3":{
                 "Key3":"Value3"
       }
}
```

I am forming this using Gson. `String Stringifiedjson = new Gson().toJson(user);`
Here is what i am trying to achive.

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
String url = "";
String event = rest.getForObject(url, Stringifiedjson);
```

1. How would i send to my REST Service and get back my result in `onEventHandler` or `onErrorHandler`. I am basically from `JavaScript` background.
2. Why does the method getForObject does not accept `String, String` as params.

**Update:**

```
AuthenticateUser user = new AuthenticateUser(credential, Header);       
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application","json"));         
//HttpEntity<AuthenticateUser> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<AuthenticateUser>(user, requestHeaders);


RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
String url = "url";             
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, AuthenticateUser.class, String.class);
```

Attached is the pastie of what exception i am getting.

http://pastie.org/private/efyfvvbxyxdsvm3lvv7q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the second question: I just found this example (you could take a look at the entire doc ;) )

[2.7.1 Basic Usage Example
The following example shows a query to google for the search term "SpringSource".](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html)

```
String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q={query}";

// Create a new RestTemplate instance
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Add the String message converter
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

// Make the HTTP GET request, marshaling the response to a String
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "SpringSource");
```

> ```
> getForObject
>
> public <T> T getForObject(URI url,
>                     Class<T> responseType)
>           throws RestClientException
> Description copied from interface: RestOperations
> Retrieve a representation by doing a GET on the URL . The response (if any) is converted and returned.
> Specified by:
> getForObject in interface RestOperations
> Parameters:
> url - the URL
> responseType - the type of the return value
> Returns:
> the converted object
> Throws:
> RestClientException
> ```

The exception in your stacktrace could be related to the same issue of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception). The problem occurs when your app tries to make a connection in the main thread.

Comment: Where am i passing my JsonObject here.... lets take i am using postForObject... but i don't see passing JsonObject here.

Comment: I guessed you were using org.springframework.web.client, is that right? Can you please add some more info on what your problem is? EDIT the answer to add part of the ref.

Comment: I have updated my post, i am using Spring-Android. What is the mistake i am doing here...

Comment: By looking at the exception... Have you given the right permission to your app?
Can you share also the skd's version you are using please?
take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception also

Answer (score 0):

```
10-23 15:46:10.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 15:46:10.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) is thrown when you execute any network operation in your application main ui thread (see also [Keeping Your App Responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html). This is not allowed. You'll have to use a background thread for network operation, see Worker threads on http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html